# How to pass variables between build/deploy tasks in a TaskGroup in VSTS 16.131.28601.4

Tags: azure-pipelines, powershell

I have a multi-configuration web application I'm using parallel deployments, leveraging Task Groups for reusing my deployment code.

I've been using Powershell tasks and the `##vso[task.setvariable variable]` but those only are readable by other tasks (particularly non-PowerShell tasks) if they correspond to top-level variables at the Build/Release level.  Variables that are only local to the task-group.

Basically, the behavior described in [Issue #3116](https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/issues/3116)

Does anybody have a better workaround for this issue besides binding all your variables right to the root with identical names?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure my approach is any "better". However, what I have done in the past was to use Table Storage or Cosmos DB to store the key-value pairs that needed to be persisted between each stage.

The general schema was:

- **Key**: *buildNum-variableName*
- **Value**: *variableValue*

I then created various wrappers for the SDK to access from PowerShell and MSBuild, this also enabled chaining multiple builds together to create a CI/CD pipeline.